# JavaScript add and remove class function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I have this problem. I have an accordion that toggles one heading open at a time and I am having a problem adding in the open/close image that sits to the right of the heading.

I have it so far so that once you click a heading it removes the 'open' image and toggles another class for the 'close' image. Now I need to basically swap out these classes again so that if you toggle another heading it removes the other image and goes back to the original.

Here is the code I am using.

**JavaScript**

```
<SCRIPT>
    $("#accordion > li").click(function () {
        $("#accordian li").removeClass("faq-header");
        $(this).addClass("faq-header2");
        if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
            $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(250);
            $('#accordion > ul').addClass('faq-header');
            $(this).removeClass("faq-header");
        }
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });

    $('#accordion > ul:eq(0)').show();
</SCRIPT>
```

**CSS**

```
#accordion {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left:-38px;
}
#accordion ul:eq {
    background-image:url(../img/faq-open.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    padding-right:20px;
}
#accordion li{
    display: block;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.faq-header {
    text-align:left;
    background-image:url(../img/faq-close.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.faq-header2 {
    text-align:left;
    background-image:url(../img/faq-open.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    margin-right:20px;
}
#accordion ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}
#accordion ul li{
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
    margin-left:-38px !important;
}
```

I have removed one class and added another class as you can see `$("#accordian li").removeClass("faq-header");` and added the following `$(this).addClass("faq-header2");`

But I need to now remove `.faq-header2` and add back `.faq-header` after it is no longer the section selected. It doesn't seem too hard to me but i just can't figure out how to code it. Should be a basic if function I would think...

Comment: jquery has a really cool plugin for accordions...why make your own when the code already exists?

Comment: Yea i have already incorporated an accordion plugin but i can't find one that toggles different images if it is open/closed. This is why i am resorting to altering the one i have

Comment: Also this is totally cross browser compatible and i haven't found a bug with it yet as i have used it in the past but not with a switch toggle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery UI accordion is a well proven cross browser widget, and does images on open and close (by default on the left, but one change of CSS will put them on the right)

as per [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

if you don't won't to use it, I would persue an option with toggleClass, [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

**EDIT**

Thanks for posting your HTML, I didn't necessarily mean the whole page, just the HTML for you accordion functionality, but hey thats cool

First point though, your HTML seems a bit heavy for just doing an accordion. Its also not entirely valid to put a ul inside a ul (they tend to go inside li, as in a drop down menu style). Further more it doesn't seem to be much point in all those ul and li as each ul only has one li anyway, just seems like a lot more tags than you would really need. ul and li tend to come with a lot of default styling (bullet points, margins, padding, indents etc), which can mean a lot more CSS than need to make them display how you want. I would have gone with a  simpler structure, makes it easier to write your jQuery. A bit more like this

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>First header</h3>
    <div>First content</div>
    <h3>Second header</h3>
    <div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

Anyway, that was just a comment from my experience. To your problem at hand, this worked for me

```
    $("#accordion > li").click(function () {              
            var self = $(this);
            self.next('ul').slideToggle(300, function () {
                if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                    self.removeClass('faq-header').addClass('faq-header2')
                }
                else {
                    self.removeClass('faq-header2').addClass('faq-header')
                }
            });
            self.siblings().removeClass('faq-header2').addClass('faq-header').next('ul').slideUp(250);
        });
```

toggleClass, although useful, in your circumstance as to how you want classes to be added and removed, may not be as useful as I would have thought

Comment: Hi OJay,
Thank you for that it is a great help. I originally was using the jQuery UI accordion but it messed with other functions i have on the page as i have a 'jQuery lightbox', a hover over drop down menu and login functions also within the same page so had to go with a bit more of a 'lightweight' model unfortunately...

I will try some more with the 'toggle' between classes function but aren't having luck so far. I have also tried appending classes but to no avail.

Comment: Cool, if you are still having trouble, put your HTML code up as well, as some of the things your doing in the jQuery seem a bit strange to me, but without the HTML I can't really say

Comment: Yea no worries thanks again. I will have to strip alot of the content because i can't show my client to everyone so that will take a little time sorry.

Comment: It isn't showing everything correctly but you get the idea of what i am trying to do. Has alot of features as the client wants... Rounded corners, pop-up login areas, dropdown hover menu, and on other pages of the site that i have got working great is a pagination feature and google integrated search as well as a rotating carousel on the main page. It is a very nice looking site once together.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#firstpane p.menu_head").click(function()
{
$(this).css({backgroundImage:"url(img/faq-open.gif)"}).next("div.menu_body").slideToggle(300).siblings("div.menu_body").slideUp("slow");
$(this).siblings().css({backgroundImage:"url(img/faq-close.gif)"});
});
$("#secondpane p.menu_head").mouseover(function()
{
$(this).css({backgroundImage:"url(img/faq-open.gif)"}).next("div.menu_body").slideDown(500).siblings("div.menu_body").slideUp("slow");
$(this).siblings().css({backgroundImage:"url(img/faq-close.gif)"});
});
    }); 
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

I think that `toggle()` function is a bit not intuitive. I usually use my pwn method replaceClass() to do as you want:

```
void replaceClass(Object classList, String surrogateClass, String classToReplace);
```

defined as follow

```
function replaceClass(elementClassList, firstClass, secondClass) {
 if(elementClassList.contains(firstClass)){
 {
  elementClassList.remove(firstClass);
elementClassList.add(secondClass);
}
}
```